# Два монитора Debian 8

Tags: debian

Как расширить рабочий стол на два монитора?
Сейчас второй монитор просто дублирует первый.

Comment: В настройках,  там нет никакой особой разницы с другими OS.

Comment: если в de имеется интерфейс (читай — «графическая обёртка») к xrandr, воспользуйтесь им, если нет, пользуйтесь напрямую xrandr.

Comment: А что значит воспользоваться напрямую xrandr?

Comment: В общем arandr помог.